# unrecognized expression: input[name

Tags: jquery

I have this input fields,

```
<input type="text" name="member[$counter]"  value=" " />

<input value="Male" name="gender[$counter]" type="radio" />
```

And I'm using jQuery to access the input name and value like this,

```
var member_name = $("input[name=member[]]").val();   
var gender = $("input[name=gender[]]").val();
```

But I'm only getting the error,

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   input[name=member'[]]'

What did I miss out?  I'm still new at jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put quotes around the attribute value:

```js
var member_name = $("input[name='member[]']").val();   
var gender = $("input[name='gender[]']").val();
console.log(member_name);
console.log(gender);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="member[]"  value="foo" />
<input value="Male" name="gender[]" type="radio" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = "<c:out value=${counter}";
var member_name = $("input[name=member["+ counter +"]]").val();   
var gender = $("input[name=gender["+ counter +"]]").val();
```

Specified the key value of member Array

Comment: Hi sir thanks for helping, I've done that and I'm getting the error,
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=member[<c:out value=${counter}]]